# How do i get millisecond values using ask time?

Tags: cics

I am writing a PLI/CICS code. Trying to figure out a way to get the time value that includes millisecond.

I have tried looking up documentation for CICS ASKTIME and FORMATTIME and did not find a good way to get the millisecond value

So in my code, i am doing a ASKTIME first , followed by the format time.

```
This is how my code looks like

/* first do a asktime */
EXEC CICS ASKTIME                          
          ABSTIME(CICS_TIMESTAMP);         

/* followed by the formattime */                                          
EXEC CICS FORMATTIME                       
          ABSTIME(CICS_TIMESTAMP)          
          TIME(CICS_TIME);
```

At this point, i am able to get the time in HHMMSS format. Can you tell me if there is a way to get the millisecond value as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXEC CICS FORMATTIME
          ABSTIME(CICS_TIMESTAMP)
          MILLISECONDS(MTIME)
```

From the [CICS manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_formattime.html)

> MILLISECONDS(data-area) 
>   Returns the number of milliseconds in the current second specified by ABSTIME, as a binary integer in the range 0 - 999.